# Title tag not showing in nextjs

Tags: server, next.js

I have created single page in nextjs, And I taken build file `<title>` and `<meta>` working fine. see the `title` tag in this image [image]

but I uploaded build file this server https://blog.simple.in/ title tag not showing. what I am missing. Could you please let me know server issue or code issue please let me know. Thanks

loyaltycards.js

```
import React, { Component } from "react"; 
import { Grid } from "semantic-ui-react"; 
import $ from "jquery"; 
import Layout from "../components/layout"; 
import 'semantic-ui-css/semantic.min.css';
import Head from 'next/head';
class Loyaltycard extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    $(".v2, .v3, .v4").hide();

    $(".m1").click(function () {
      $(".v1").show();
      $(".v2,.v3,.v4").hide();
      $(".li-1").addClass("btn-active-1");
      $(".btn-active-2").removeClass("btn-active-2");
      $(".btn-active-3").removeClass("btn-active-3");
      $(".btn-active-4").removeClass("btn-active-4");
    });
    $(".m2").click(function () {
      $(".v2").show();
      $(".v1,.v3,.v4").hide();
      $(".li-2").addClass("btn-active-2");
      $(".btn-active-1").removeClass("btn-active-1");
      $(".btn-active-3").removeClass("btn-active-3");
      $(".btn-active-4").removeClass("btn-active-4");
    });
    $(".m3").click(function () {
      $(".v3").show();
      $(".v1,.v2,.v4").hide();
      $(".li-3").addClass("btn-active-3");
      $(".btn-active-2").removeClass("btn-active-2");
      $(".btn-active-1").removeClass("btn-active-1");
      $(".btn-active-4").removeClass("btn-active-4");
    });
    $(".m4").click(function () {
      $(".v4").show();
      $(".v1,.v2,.v3").hide();
      $(".li-4").addClass("btn-active-4");
      $(".btn-active-2").removeClass("btn-active-2");
      $(".btn-active-1").removeClass("btn-active-1");
      $(".btn-active-3").removeClass("btn-active-3");
    });
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <Layout>
      <Head>
              <meta charSet="utf-8" />
              <title>Store all your rewards cards on your phone</title>
              <meta name="description" content="The smart, easy way to carry all Loyalty, Reward and Club cards on your mobile- link them all in the simple  app, checkout as usual and earn points at stores." /> 
              <meta name="google-site-verification" content="rtIRrUNRpgZ_lFtlfS8LJ0-8j_d569BXS9NOGa_nM6Y" />
              <link rel="canonical" href="https://simple .cash/loyaltycards"/>
            </Head>
        
        <Grid className="static-sections">
          <Grid.Column width={1}></Grid.Column>
          <Grid.Column width={14} className="promotions">
            <h1>Loyalty Cards</h1>
            <p>
              Got a wallet full of store loyalty cards? Link them all in the
              simple  app and start earning points at stores you visit all the
              time. simple  app allows you to store all of your rewards cards on
              your phone. Shop and use your loyalty account at checkout as usual
              to collect points. Turn your phone into your wallet and redefine
              your everyday shopping experience! It is the smart and easy way to
              carry all Loyalty cards, Reward cards and Club cards on your
              smartphone with simple .
            </p>
          </Grid.Column>
          <Grid.Column width={1}></Grid.Column>
        </Grid>

        <Grid>
          <Grid.Column width={1}></Grid.Column>
          <Grid.Column width={14} className="loyalty">
            <Grid>
              <Grid.Column width={8} className="left-eight">
                <div className="m1" onClick={this.m1}>
                  <div class="media-left">
                    <p class="li-circle-second-1 li-1">1</p>
                  </div>
                  <div class="media-body">
                    <h4 class="media-heading">Select Card</h4>
                    <p>
                      Select a card from the available list. If not available,
                      add your card by selecting Add New
                    </p>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div className="m2" onClick={this.m2}>
                  <div class="media-left">
                    <p class="li-circle-second-2 li-2">2</p>
                  </div>
                  <div class="media-body">
                    <h4 class="media-heading">Scan barcode</h4>
                    <p>Scan the barcode from the actual card you carry</p>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div className="m3" onClick={this.m3}>
                  <div class="media-left">
                    <p class="li-circle-second-3 li-3">3</p>
                  </div>
                  <div class="media-body">
                    <h4 class="media-heading">Card Photo</h4>
                    <p>
                      Click a photo of the front & back of the card. (Optional)
                    </p>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div className="m4" onClick={this.m4}>
                  <div class="media-left">
                    <p class="li-circle-second-4 li-4">4</p>
                  </div>
                  <div class="media-body">
                    <h4 class="media-heading">Use the Card</h4>
                    <p>
                      During checkout at the store, select the appropriate card
                      from the app & show at the counter for scanning
                    </p>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </Grid.Column>
              <Grid.Column width={8}>
                <div className="v1">
                  <video
                    playsinline={"playsinline"}
                    autoplay={"autoplay"}
                    muted={"muted"}
                    loop={"loop"}
                  >
                    <source
                      class="embed-responsive-item"
                      src="/mp4/loyalty-card/1-loyalty-card.mp4"
                      type="video/mp4"
                    ></source>
                  </video>
                </div>
                <div className="v2">
                  <video
                    playsinline={"playsinline"}
                    autoplay={"autoplay"}
                    muted={"muted"}
                    loop={"loop"}
                  >
                    <source
                      class="embed-responsive-item"
                      src="/mp4/loyalty-card/2-scan-barcode.mp4"
                      type="video/mp4"
                    ></source>
                  </video>
                </div>
                <div className="v3">
                  <video
                    playsinline={"playsinline"}
                    autoplay={"autoplay"}
                    muted={"muted"}
                    loop={"loop"}
                  >
                    <source
                      class="embed-responsive-item"
                      src="/mp4/loyalty-card/3-card-photo.mp4"
                      type="video/mp4"
                    ></source>
                  </video>
                </div>
                <div className="v4">
                  <video
                    playsinline={"playsinline"}
                    autoplay={"autoplay"}
                    muted={"muted"}
                    loop={"loop"}
                  >
                    <source
                      class="embed-responsive-item"
                      src="/mp4/loyalty-card/4-cashback-added.mp4"
                      type="video/mp4"
                    ></source>
                  </video>
                </div>
              </Grid.Column>
            </Grid>
          </Grid.Column>
          <Grid.Column width={1}></Grid.Column>
        </Grid> 
      </Layout>
    );
  }
}

export default Loyaltycard;
```

Comment: Your code looks fine. The website you linked isn't currently available, though.

Comment: Wow, why are you really using jQuery and componentDidMount()  with next js?

Comment: I am experiencing the same issue. Any news on that?